# Can someone migrate [specific question on main]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, migration, specific-question

Can someone migrate [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17451/is-there-a-general-way-to-convert-a-critical-section-to-one-or-more-semaphores) to either cs.stackexchange or stackoverflow?

10 or so hours ago I flagged it as off topic because I wasn't allowed

to suggest cs.stackexchange as a migration target, but after looking

at it again, I think stackoverflow would be a better site for it.

(Also, was "discussion" the right one of the four bold tags for this?)

Comment: Yes, discussion is the right tag.